# I am subscribing to a subscription and getting duplicate items in my view with Angular 6 I am not sure why

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have put the code below. I have a post service which follows and unfollows posts and adds their id to an array which is an Observable. I am getting the items to display in the view as I want but when I push to the followedPostsArray it will push 1 + every item that may have already been in the followedPostsArray.

Also when I unfollow the view does not change.

Component.ts

```
 this.postService.getFollowedPosts().subscribe((followedPosts) => {
        followedPosts.forEach((postId) => {
            this.frApiService.GetPostById(postId).subscribe((post) => {
                this.followedPostsArray.push(post);
                console.log(this.followedPostsArray);
            });
        });
    });
```

Component.html

```
    <div class="item lib-flex" *ngFor="let post of followedPostsArray; let i = index;">
    <div class="title lib-grow" (click)="loadPost(post)">
        {{post?.title | shortenContentPipe}}
        <span (click)="unfollow(post, $event)">UNFOLLOW</span>
    </div>
    <div class="time lib-flex lib-main-center lib-cross-center lib-pr5">
        <i class="icon icon-Clock lib-mr5"></i>
        {{getAge(post?.latestCommentDateTime)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Is the output correct at start and then repeats with every follow/unfollow action?

Comment: I click the follow button then their is one item in array and 1 item displays on the screen. I click follow on a second item and then 3 items display to the screen the 1st item twice and then the second item if I click an additional item the 1st item will be added 3 times the 2nd item twice and the 3rd item finally

Comment: Please, provide the code for the entire follow action. I need to see which function you call and how.

Comment: Ok so this.postService.getFollowedPosts() is here 
    ` getFollowedPosts(): Observable<any> {
        return this.followedPosts.asObservable();
    }`
then I call GetPostById 
   `GetPostById(postId: number): Observable<PostView> {
        const url: string = this.baseUrl + this.applicationId + '/Post/' + postId;
        return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map((response) => {
            return FrApiService.extractData(response);
        }).catch(FrApiService.handleError);
    }`

Comment: Then code for the click action is too long to put here.

Comment: Ok. Please find my answer below.

Comment: It is most likely caused by this line `followedPosts.forEach((postId) =>` you are looping every items everytime, and everytime it increases when you click on the button

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in not clearing `followedPostsArray`. Interpreting the code given and your additional subscription I'd guess you reload all posts when you add a new one to follow.

You have to reset the array first. I still don't know which method your follow-button calls so I improvise with a sybolic name.

```
followPost() {
    // reset the array
    this.followedPostsArray = [];

     // only then call the service
     this.postService.getFollowedPosts(...);
}
```

This is supposed to stop your repeating entries.